# plot an item in a list which keeps updating in Netlogo

Tags: list, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I defined a set of attributes for some producer agents in the interface as global variables and then assigned them to a list (in the setup) which is also global and the agents will use its content.

The problem is that I cannot plot them.

Defined in the interface as global variables : `p1-size = 9, p2-size = 13, p3-size = 14.5, p1-rate = 80, p2-rate = 50, p3-rate = 98`

```
to setup

  ca  ; clear-all
  reset-ticks
  file-close-all
  setup-patches
  create-prod ; create producers
  set size-set ((list p1-size p2-size p3-size))
  set rate-set ((list p1-rate p2-rate p3-rate))
```

I want to plot and monitor how the rates changes, and I encounter an error by defining this :

```
plot item  0 size-set
```

Size-set is global, but the error says "ITEM expected to be a string or list but got the number 0 instead.

I'd appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`reset-ticks`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reset-ticks) primitive has the side effect of updating the plots. In your code, you're calling `reset-ticks` *before* setting the value of `size-set`, so at the time your plot calls `plot item 0 size-set`, your `size-set` global still has its default value of `0`.

Two potential solutions:

- Move `reset-ticks` to the end of your `setup` procedure. That way, `size-set` will be correctly initialized when your plot is updated. Unless you have a very particular reason to do otherwise, this is the solution you should choose. It is the standard in NetLogo to call `reset-ticks` only at the end of `setup`.
- You shouldn't do this unless you have a good reason, but you could also have some sort of "guard condition" in your plotting statement: `if is-list? size-set [ plotxy ticks item 0 size-set ]`. Notice the use of [`plotxy`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plotxy) instead of [`plot`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#plot) to ensure that you're still plotting at the correct *x* position even if your guard condition causes you to skip some ticks.